# Having problems with clicking on hedings after getting json ajax data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problems with clicking on table headings (asc, dsc) when press the button for getting json ajax data from php which builds my table. I use function sortresult by table headings for sorting values in table. Function sort result builds my table. 
I recive json data successful.

If I don't use button for showing data (just a lit bit change code), automaticaly get json with ajax and creating the table then the clicking is working fine. What colud be the problem for not working with button?

So i have function:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#submit').click(function(event){
         $('#headings th').click(function(){
             $('#results').html("");
         var id=$(this).attr('id');
         var asc =(!$(this).attr('asc'));
         $('#headings th').each(function () {
             $(this).removeAttr('asc');
         });
             if(asc) $(this).attr('asc','asc');
        sortResult(id, asc);
         });
     showResult();
 });
 });
```

Function sortResult:

```
 function sortResult(prop, asc){
      var val=null; 
      dataOut = dataOut.sort(function(a,b){
      if(asc) return (a[prop] > b[prop]);
          else return (b[prop] > a[prop]);
      });
      showResult();
 }
```

Function showresult:

```
 function showResult(){
      var html='';
      for (var i in dataOut){
           html +='<tr>'
           +'<td>'+dataOut[i].email+'</td>'
           ...
           +'</tr>'
      }
      html+='</table>'
      $('#results').html(html);
 }
```

Comment: It's almost always wrong to bind click handlers inside the click handler function of another element. That means the second click handler won't be available until after you click the first element. And then every time you click the first element, it will add more handlers to the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you dynamically create elements, you need to register for the events with [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(body).on("click", "#headings th", function(){
         $('#results').html("");
         var id=$(this).attr('id');
         var asc =(!$(this).attr('asc'));
         $('#headings th').each(function () {
              $(this).removeAttr('asc');
         });
         if(asc) $(this).attr('asc','asc');
         sortResult(id, asc);
     });
     $('#submit').click(function(event){
       showResult();
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the element you're clicking is added by the ajax request you will need to use jQuery 'on' instead of 'click'.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(event){
        $('#headings th').on('click', function(){
            $('#results').html("");
            var id=$(this).attr('id');
            var asc =(!$(this).attr('asc'));
            $('#headings th').each(function () {
                $(this).removeAttr('asc');
            });
            if(asc) $(this).attr('asc','asc');
            sortResult(id, asc);
        });
        showResult();
   });
});
```